# Appium Environmental Variables Error

Tags: android, appium

My system not detecting Android Studio Environmental variables.

Currently Using
Appium v 1.6.4
Java jdk1.8.0_121
Nodejs v 6.10.2
Andriod Studio v 2.3.1

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information

Comment: You also need to restart the command prompt after setting variables

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually set ANDROID_HOME in your path? If not, you will need to add the Android SDK to path before you can proceed. I don't know what version of Windows you are using, but the steps should be pretty much the same for 7/8/8.1/10. Check http://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/ for more information.

Comment: Yes, Done the same method. but, still getting same error.